# Azure website PHP vhosts

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, vhosts

I have a website set up on Azure which I'd like to deploy a PHP site to.

In WAMP I have the following vhosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:9898>
        ServerAdmin wayne@localhost
        ServerName test.somesite.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\somesite-ui\www"

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Directory "C:\wamp\www\somesite-ui\www">

                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Rewrite configuration
        Include "C:\wamp\www\somesite-ui\rewrite.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is because we're using Atsumi MVC

How can I configure the Azure website to use a similar config?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this answer will help you. But instead of just creating a php web site, you could create a VM first with any operating system, and enable http end points to the vm. Install Apache server on the vm and do the necessary configuration. ( Or you coudld simply install WAMP in it)

azure web sites has the address lite somthing.azuresites.net (not sure)
azure vm will have "somthing.cloudapp.net" so the domain name won't be a much problem for you.

I have written a blog post on [How to create a VM on azure](http://testedandwrote.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-create-virtual-machine-in-azure.html). You could use it if you like.

Comment: Thing is doing it this way I lose all of the GitHub deployment stuff

Comment: Hi iwayneo, I really did not understand how are you going to lose your github deployements. could you please explain me more?

Comment: you can set a site up in Azure and then choose to deploy from a github branch. When I push to that branch a hook is fired and azure automatically publishes the site.

Comment: That approach is better than the way I suggested.. Thanks for pointing that out. :)